# A non-numeric value encountered ajax laravel

Tags: php, ajax, laravel

My form is like this

[image: form]

I'm working on a project and I would like to know which is the best way to showing the data after having to insert a record on the database having a complex structure HTML between using the structure in Laravel or jQuery.

I'm building a system of jobs. When the user writes the post and publishes it a call ajax triggers the function Laravel and it inserts the information on the database. until here all OK, but then I have to display the message insert on the wall of the user, so did not work.

```
    <form id="job-store" method="post">
        <input type="hidden" value="{{ route('job.store') }}" name="url" />
        @csrf
        <div class="row">
            <div class="col-md-6 mb-3">
                <label for="employment_type">نوع استخدام</label>
                <select class="form-control selectpicker" title="چیزی انتخاب نشده است" id="employment_type" name="employment_type">
                    <option value="حق التدریس">حق التدریس</option>
                    <option value="رسمی">رسمی</option>
                    <option value="پیمانی">پیمانی</option>
                    <option value="قراردادی">قراردادی</option>
                </select>
            </div>
            <div class="col-md-6 mb-3">
                <label for="job_type">عنوان شغلی</label>
                <select class="form-control selectpicker" title="چیزی انتخاب نشده است" id="job_type" name="job_type">
                    <option value="مربی درون سازمانی">مربی درون سازمانی</option>
                    <option value="مربی حق التدریس">مربی حق التدریس</option>
                    <option value="صنعتکار">صنعتکار</option>
                    <option value="مدرس دانشگاه">مدرس دانشگاه</option>
                    <option value="استادکار مهارتی">استادکار مهارتی</option>
                    <option value="سایر">سایر</option>
                </select>
            </div>
            <div class="col-md-6 mb-3">
                <label for="history">سابقه (سال)</label>
                <input type="text" class="form-control" id="history" name="history">
            </div>
            <div class="col-md-6 mb-3">
                <label for="post_title">عنوان پست</label>
                <input type="text" class="form-control" id="post_title" name="post_title">
            </div>
            <div class="col-md-6 mb-3">
                <label for="state">استان محل خدمت</label>
                <input type="text" class="form-control" id="state" name="state">
            </div>
            <div class="col-md-6 mb-3">
                <label for="city">شهر محل خدمت</label>
                <input type="text" class="form-control" id="city" name="city">
            </div>
            <div class="col-md-6 mb-3">
                <label for="start_date">تاریخ شروع به كار</label>
                <date-picker type="date" id="start_date" name="start_date"></date-picker>
            </div>
            <div class="col-md-6 mb-3">
                <label for="end_date">تاریخ خاتمه كار</label>
                <date-picker type="date" id="end_date" name="end_date"></date-picker>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="row">
            <div class="col-md-6 mb-3">
                <button type="submit" class="btn btn-success job-store"><i class="fas fa-plus fa-xs"></i> افزودن</button>
            </div>
        </div>
    </form>
    <div class="table-responsive">
        <table class="table table-striped">
            <thead>
            <tr>
                <th>ردیف</th>
                <th>نوع استخدام</th>
                <th>تاریخ شروع کار</th>
                <th>تاریخ خاتمه کار</th>
                <th>استان محل خدمت</th>
                <th>شهر محل خدمت</th>
                <th>اکشن</th>
            </tr>
            </thead>
            <tbody id="showJobs">

            </tbody>
        </table>
    </div>
    
    @section('script')
        <script>
            $(document).ready(function (e) {
                $('.job-store').on('click',(function(e) {
                    e.preventDefault();
                    var formData = new FormData($('#job-store')[0]);
                    let url = $('#job-store :input')[0].getAttribute('value');
                    $.ajax({
                        type:'POST',
                        url,
                        data:formData,
                        cache:false,
                        contentType: false,
                        processData: false,
                        success:function(data){
                            console.log("success");
                            console.log(data);
                            showJobs(data);
                        },
                        error: function(data){
                            console.log("error");
                            console.log(data);
                        }
                    });
                }));
                function showJobs(data) {
                    let html = '';
                    $.each(data, function (key, val) {
                        $('#data').append("<tr>"+
                            "<td>"+val.id+"</td>"+
                            "<td>"+val.employment_type+"</td>"+
                            "<td>"+val.start_date+"</td>"+
                            "<td>"+val.end_date+"</td>"+
                            "<td>"+val.state+"</td>"+
                            "<td>"+val.city+"</td>"+
                            "<td>"+
                            '<form action="{{ route('job.destroy',+'val.id') }}" method="post">'+
                            '@csrf'+
                            '@method('DELETE')'+
                            '<div class="btn-group">'+
                            '<a href="{{ route('job.edit',+'val.id') }}" class="btn btn-info btn-sm">Edit</a>'+
                            '<button type="submit" class="btn btn-danger btn-sm">Delete</button>'+
                            '</div>'+
                            '</form>'+
                            "</td>"+
                            "</tr>"
                        )});
                    $('#showJobs').append(html);
                }
            });
        </script>
    @endsection
```

Controller

```
<?php

namespace App\Http\Controllers;

use App\Http\Requests\JobRequest;
use App\Job;
use Illuminate\Http\Request;

class JobController extends Controller
{
    public function store(Request $request)
    {
        Job::create([
            'user_id' => auth()->id(),
            'employment_type' => $request->employment_type,
            'job_type' => $request->job_type,
            'post_title' => $request->post_title,
            'history' => $request->history,
            'state' => $request->state,
            'city' => $request->city,
            'start_date' => $request->start_date,
            'end_date' => $request->end_date,
        ]);
        return redirect()->back();
    }

    public function edit(Job $job)
    {
        return view('Home.edits.job', compact('job'));
    }

    public function update(Request $request, Job $job)
    {
        $data = [
            'employment_type' => $request->employment_type,
            'job_type' => $request->job_type,
            'post_title' => $request->post_title,
            'history' => $request->history,
            'state' => $request->state,
            'city' => $request->city,
            'start_date' => $request->start_date,
            'end_date' => $request->end_date,
        ];
        $job->update($data);
        return redirect()->route('home');
    }
    public function destroy(Job $job)
    {
        $job->delete();
        return redirect()->back();
    }
}
```

It is my console

[image: console]

I get this error

[image: error]

Comment: you cant pass JavaScript  value to route method. Can you show controller method

Comment: Can you try to console.log(val) and console.log(val.id)?

Answer (score 0):

Instead of appending in javascript better create view for that file and return view from controller

First controller must return view or json but it returning redirect back.

```
  public function store(Request $request)
  {
       Job::create([
            'user_id' => auth()->id(),
            'employment_type' => $request->employment_type,
            'job_type' => $request->job_type,
            'post_title' => $request->post_title,
            'history' => $request->history,
            'state' => $request->state,
            'city' => $request->city,
            'start_date' => $request->start_date,
            'end_date' => $request->end_date,
        ]);
       $jobs= Job::get();
        return view('jobdetail',compact('jobs'));
   }
```

and jobdetail blade

```
@foreach($jobsas $key=>$value)
        <tr>
            <td>{{$value->id}}</td>
            <td>{{$value->employment_type}}</td>
            <td>{{$value->start_date}}</td>
            <td>{{$value->end_date}}</td>
            <td>{{$value->state}}</td>
            <td>{{$value->city}}</td>
            <td>
                <form action={{ route('job.destroy',$value->id) }} method=post>
                    @csrf
                    @method('DELETE')
                    <div class=btn-group>
                        <a href={{ route('job.edit',$value->id) }} class=btn btn-info btn-sm>Edit</a>
                        <button type=submit class=btn btn-danger btn-sm>Delete</button>
                    </div>
                </form>
            </td>
        </tr>
    @endforeach
```

and in JavaScript

```
 $.ajax({
       type:'POST',
       url,
       data:formData,
       cache:false,
       contentType: false,
       processData: false,
       success:function(data){
               $('#showJobs').html(data);
              },
       error: function(data){
                 console.log("error");
                 console.log(data);
              }
    });
```

Also if you want to append last created job detail then

```
public function store(Request $request)
      {
           $job=Job::create([
                'user_id' => auth()->id(),
                'employment_type' => $request->employment_type,
                'job_type' => $request->job_type,
                'post_title' => $request->post_title,
                'history' => $request->history,
                'state' => $request->state,
                'city' => $request->city,
                'start_date' => $request->start_date,
                'end_date' => $request->end_date,
            ]);
           
            return view('jobdetail',compact('job'));
       }
```

then in view jobdetail

```
<tr>
            <td>{{$job->id}}</td>
            <td>{{$job->employment_type}}</td>
            <td>{{$job->start_date}}</td>
            <td>{{$job->end_date}}</td>
            <td>{{$job->state}}</td>
            <td>{{$job->city}}</td>
            <td>
                <form action={{ route('job.destroy',$job->id) }} method=post>
                    @csrf
                    @method('DELETE')
                    <div class=btn-group>
                        <a href={{ route('job.edit',$job->id) }} class=btn btn-info btn-sm>Edit</a>
                        <button type=submit class=btn btn-danger btn-sm>Delete</button>
                    </div>
                </form>
            </td>
        </tr>
```

and in JavaScript

```
 $.ajax({
        type:'POST',
        url,
        data:formData,
        cache:false,
        contentType: false,
       processData: false,
       success:function(data){
                $('#showJobs').append(data);
               },
       error: function(data){
               console.log("error");
               console.log(data);
              }
       });
```

Comment: No, I want this to be done only with Ajax

Comment: @DeveloperLaravel you cant pass javacript variable to route method.

Comment: @DeveloperLaravel .i have updated answer also

Comment: My problem did not sole yet, Have you AnyDesk?